# How to set the distance between the buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a problem with my xml file.
I have two buttons with custom size.
I would like to resize buttons to the similar size in relation to the screens.

On the picture 1 you can see how big they should be.

[image]

On the picture 2 you can see that they are too far away and small.

[image]

I know that I didn't set it correct. (mainly android:layout_width) But how to set that?

Here is my xml code:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#99000099" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#99990000" />
```

Thanks for reply! :)

Comment: What layout do you use as a container of them?

Comment: Post your complete layout file and clarify your question more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to use a `LinearLayout` to wrap the buttons, you can put that at the bottom and then set the weights of the buttons to 1 each, which means they'll take up half the screen each.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#99000099" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#99990000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that you can change the margins on the buttons in order to space them apart and away from the edges too, like your first picture.